# Pegar text da LinkLabel criada em runtime C#

Tags: c#

Estou criando algumas `LinkLabel` em tempo de execução com o código abaixo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < qtdresp; i++)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel Lbl = 
        new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel();
        
    pnlFull.Controls.Add(Lbl);
    Lbl.Text = trilhas.Rows[i]["duvida"].ToString();
    Lbl.Top = pos;
    pos += 30;
    Lbl.Left = 20;
    Lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    Lbl.Width = 250;
    Lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopRight;
    Lbl.Font = new Font("Raleway", 10);
    
    Lbl.LinkClicked += 
        new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(Lbl_LinkClicked);
}
```

e o resultado é esse aqui:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Agora como faço para saber em qual dos dois a pessoa clicou?
- Precisa pegar esse `text` da `LinkLabel` para fazer meu próximo `select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E evento de click recebe dois parâmetros, `sender` e `e` que são respectivamente o quem disparou o evento e os argumentos dele.

Então se você acessar o sender, ele será o próprio linklabel:

```
for (int i = 0; i < qtdresp; i++)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel Lbl = 
        new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel();
        
    pnlFull.Controls.Add(Lbl);
    Lbl.Name = "link"+i; //Definindo um nome chave para o controle, também é possível acessa-lo posteriomente.
    Lbl.Text = trilhas.Rows[i]["duvida"].ToString();
    Lbl.Tag = "http://google.com.br"; //Use a Tag para algum dado associado ao controle
    Lbl.Top = pos;
    pos += 30;
    Lbl.Left = 20;
    Lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    Lbl.Width = 250;
    Lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopRight;
    Lbl.Font = new Font("Raleway", 10);
    
    Lbl.LinkClicked += (_sender,_e)=>{
         System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel linkLabel = _sender as System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel;
         string url = linkLabel.Tag.ToString();
         string texto = linkLabel.Text;
         string nome = linkLabel.Name;
         
    };
}
```

---

Você pode usar um operador Lambda e montar a expressão do evento ainda dentro do escopo do controle, podendo acessar as variáveis dentro do laço do for.

```
for (int i = 0; i < qtdresp; i++)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel Lbl = 
        new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel();
        
    pnlFull.Controls.Add(Lbl);
    Lbl.Name = "link"+i; //Definindo um nome chave para o controle, também é possível acessa-lo posteriomente.
    Lbl.Text = trilhas.Rows[i]["duvida"].ToString();
    Lbl.Top = pos;
    pos += 30;
    Lbl.Left = 20;
    Lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    Lbl.Width = 250;
    Lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopRight;
    Lbl.Font = new Font("Raleway", 10);
    
    Lbl.LinkClicked += (_sender,_e)=>{
       MessageBox.Show("Clicou no link" + i + "Url = "+trilhas.Rows[i]["url"].ToString());
    };
}
```

Outras formas de fazer:

...

```
Lbl.LinkClicked += LinkLabel1_LinkClicked;
```

...

```
private void LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel linkLabel = sender as System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel;
         string url = linkLabel.Tag.ToString();
         string texto = linkLabel.Text;
         string nome = linkLabel.Name;
    }
```

Comment: Excelente explicação! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

use o objeto Lbl_LinkClicked.Text  na função LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler
compare ele com sua lista de Strings;

```
int identificador = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < qtdresp; i++)
{
    if(trilhas.Rows[i]["duvida"].ToString() == Lbl_LinkClicked.Text)
     {
        identificador = i;
        break;
     }

}

if(identificador  != -1)
{
  //o i será seu identificador da string clicada.

  trilhas.Rows[identificador]["duvida"].ToString()
}
```